# Date manipulation arithmetic in lotusscript

Tags: date, lotusscript

**Note: I am not using `notesdatetime` class for efficiency. using native arithmetic in lotusscript is 10 times faster which is critical in my application.**

I start with two date/times and adjust one to become equal to the other by using `TimeNumber` to add 15 minutes to the LotusScript `Date` variable.

How can `ahEnd` be greater than aStart? Run the code and see!

```
Dim aStart As double, ahStart As Double, ahEnd As double

aStart = CDat("18/May/2013 10:45:00: AM")
ahStart = CDat("18/May/2013 10:15:00 AM")
ahEnd = ahStart + TimeNumber (0, 30, 0)

If ahEnd > aStart Then
    MsgBox ahEnd & " is greater than " & aStart & " ?? Incorrect!"
Else 
    MsgBox ahEnd & " is NOT greater than " & aStart & ". Correct!"
End If
```

Comment: converting the variables to String and then to Double seems to work around the problem but I still don't understand why.  ie: 

    If (cDbl(cStr(ahEnd)) > cDbl(cStr(aStart)) Then...

Comment: Doubles are floating point numbers. They don't have the precise values you think they do. So adding 30 minutes is just adding the nearest possible approximation. A native compare sees the inequality. The conversion rounds the values, making them equal.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that would explain it.  So is the conversion adequate for the purpose of comparing date/times down to the second (ie no precision is lost behond Hours:Minutes:Seconds)?

Comment: I believe that is the case.